# Android SQLite rawquery not working for a query that works in sqlite3 command line & dbeaver

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an android app for a condo complex to aid locating utilities for residents.  I have multiple tables and am having trouble retrieving data from 1 of them, but only for 1 query out of 3.  Note that I am using SQLiteDatabase.rawquery.  Also, the query works in sqlite3 command line and dbeaver.  The first usage of the app should have the column 'yours' all 0's (boolean false) and let the user later set theirs to 1 (true).  So, first call should return no rows.  Later calls 1 row.

Table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE units (
building int4 NOT NULL,
unit int4 NULL,
stack int4 NULL,
unit_id int4 NOT NULL,
stack_id int4 NOT NULL,
yours int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT units_pk PRIMARY KEY (unit_id));
```

Query that fails in android but works in command line & dbeaver is as follows.  I copied the non-args version straight into command line and it works aside from adding the semicolon.  The args variation did not work either.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM units WHERE yours = 1";
    //String query = "SELECT * FROM units WHERE yours = ?";
    //String[] args = new String[]{"1"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //cursor = db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

The following 2 queries work, one with the asterisk (*) wildcard.

```
        List<String> units = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT unit FROM units WHERE building = " + buildingSelected
                   + " ORDER BY unit";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM units ORDER BY unit_id", null);
```

I am at a loss as to what is wrong and can't find an answer on the internet based upon my questions.

10/2/2019 Added the following to explain "not working".

From sqlite3 command line, ran the SQL statement to select all rows where yours = 1.  No rows come back as expected since all rows have yours = 0 (false).  Then update 1 row to set yours to 1.  Ran same SQL statement and get 1 row as expected.

```
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
electric_meters  gas_meters       units            water_valves
sqlite> SELECT * FROM units WHERE yours = 1;
sqlite>
sqlite> UPDATE units SET yours = 1 WHERE unit_id = 4561205;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM units WHERE yours = 1;
4561|205|5|4561205|45615|1
sqlite>
```

Run UPDATE again to put row back to yours = 0 to run app in studio.  Updated code after rawQuery call to getCount() in variable rows.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //cursor = db.rawQuery(query, args);

        int rows = cursor.getCount();
```

And while I am gathering this information, I found a code error that was causing issues with the debug output.  While the data looks valid with the right formats, I am not expecting rows to return but the 2 rows returned do have yours = 1.  Note the code error was after the rawQuery call and during the extraction of the values in cursor into a Unit class instance.

This is probably bad form to change my question in the middle.  The database I am looking at through sqlite3 command line is in the assets directory of the project.  The app is using the one on the AVD under /data/user/0/....  They might be different.  I have done a clean project a few times.  I thought that would reset everything, including updating the database the app uses in the AVD.  Can someone tell me how to make sure the database in the project gets repopulated into the AVD data structure?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: Also read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid for a more efficient table schema.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.  Turns out the database in the AVD file structure was not getting updated when I thought it would: clean project, synchronise files, etc.  The AVD database had values for yours = 1, so it was responding correctly.  Ended up deleting the databases and then uploading from the assets project folder.  Probably a better way, but I could not find it.  Thanks.